# compress html code

Tags: html

Just a quick question, I have seen some web page if I click view page source, the html code is compressed, if I want my html code to be compressed like that, is there a function doing the compression or I need to use come compress tool to do it before the webpage is loaded on line? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is 'compressed', do you have an example? If you mean it was all on one line they may just be using different newline charactors.

Comment: This is usually a feature in the web server, and sometimes is done in the server-side programming language you use to generate HTML (if applicable). So, you need to tell us which server you use (IIS, Apache, etc..) to tell you how to compress in it, and if it's a dynamic page, then also tell the server side programming language you use.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "minimizing". It's used a *lot* in JavaScript to keep bandwidth down. "Compression" generally means data transformation to reduce space and increase entropy, e.g. Huffman, arithmetic, or LZ-whatever coding.

Comment: @serdails, yes, you are right, I mean all on one line

Comment: @Mohamed Meligy, it's apache, I used php for serverside programming, so please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a PHP/*nix guy, but since we have been chatting about it in comments, check these..

For PHP:

- http://davidwalsh.name/compress-xhtml-page-output-php-output-buffers

For Apache:

- [http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/modules.html#Apache_*GzipChain*__compress_HTML__or_anything__in_the_OutputChain](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/modules.html#Apache__GzipChain___compress_HTML__or_anything__in_the_OutputChain)
- http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Check this discussion as well:

- http://forums.macnn.com/79/developer-center/276604/compressing-html-output-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

There are tools available for that purpose, basically these tools remove blank lines from the html code. Search for html optimizer or blank space remover tools on google and you'll find many easily.

If you are using j2ee, there are filter available (as jars), which you can download and edit your web.xml file to use them. They will remove the blank spaces when the page is being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If for "compressed" you mean without whitespaces, without line breaks, without tabs, etc, yes, there exist tools that could do the job for you, although it would be easy to write a personalized script.

By example, see [this](http://www.textfixer.com/js/compress-html.js) script. [Here](http://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php) you have the live demo.